# Is launch { whenStarted {} } and launchWhenStarted {} exactly the same?

Tags: android, coroutine, activity-lifecycle, coroutinescope

Is the below exactly the same?

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    whenStarted { 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

and

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    // Do something
}
```

Or they do have some distinct purpose, hence both APIs are provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    // Do something
}
```

Is just short hand for

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    whenStarted { 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But something you can do is

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    //do something here in general
    whenStarted { 
        // Do something onStart
    }
    whenCreated {
        // Do something onCreate
    }
    whenResumed {
        // Do something onResume
    }
}
```

At the end of the day methods:
`launchWhenStarted` &
`launchWhenResumed` &
`launchWhenCreated`
are all on the chopping  block. They will be removed in the future according to Android themselves. So I would avoid using them even if it saves you a line or two.

Source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope

Comment: Brilliant. They are the same, except one gives us more flexibility. I think just keeping one (the one that is more flexible) makes sense, else it is confusing.

Comment: What are the alternatives to launchWhenStarted...?

Comment: The functionality above is deprecated, as of now. But looking at the provided documentation, you'll see they provide a new solution called `repeatOnLifecycle`

Comment: Actually `repeatOnLifecycle` is not always a replacement for `launchWhenXXX`, because `launchWhenXXX` executes code one time, while`repeatOnLifecycle` repeats code execution every time on corresponding lifecycle state.

Comment: @Myroslav `repeatOnLifecycle ` is totally a different thing!